# Change app name appeared in Google authorization page when using Google login

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I have implemented Google signin and it works fine but I have a little problem with the app name appeared in Google authorization page after pressing Google login button. I'm guessing it's from bundleId but not sure. Is there any way to change that name without changing bundleId? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can change the name in this link.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

Select your project >> credentials >> OAuth consent screen >> Product name shown to users

Check the images

[image]

[image]

Comment: any updates to this? Looks totally different now...

Answer (score 4):

The process was similar for me but the url is different. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/apis/credentials/consent

Select your project >> click on **OAuth Consent Screen** on the left nav >> then click **EDIT APP** >> On the next screen you can change your app name:

[image: Oauth Consent Screen]

[image: App Registration Screen]