# google sing in shows project id instead of project name

Tags: ios, react-native, google-signin

I have configured google sign in for my mobile apps written in ReacNative using [google-signin-react](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin) package . For android device everything work correct, but in ios device when you want to login it shows project number instead of name(showed in screenshot).

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036919/7250862

Comment: Thanks it work for me.